# Sorting Dictionary first by value , then by keys in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, key-value

i sorted a Dict by value but when the values are equal, keys should be sorted alphabetically.
I want my output to be sorted descending by their value and then ascending (A-Z) by their key (alphabetically)

Comment: Pls show some sample data, so the types of your keys and values are known. Also, what output do you expect? Print or a list of items...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_dictionary = dict({'ca': 'a', 'cb': 'c', 'n': 'b', 'd': 'z', 'f': 'a'})
l=my_dictionary.items() # get a list of (k, v)
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0],reverse=False) # sort by key in ascending order
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True) # sort by value in descending order
ordered_keys=[t[0] for t in l] # get an ordered list of the keys
```

This code gives you a sorted list of keys which can you use to access the values in the order you want